# ARM Template: How to create connection to storage from different resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to write an ARM template to deploy a connection to the storage account for my Logic App. The problem is that my Logic App belongs to one resource group & the storage account in another.

When I run the deployment pipeline I get the following deployment error:

> The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/*StorageAccountName*'
> under resource group '*Logic App Resource Group*' was not found.

I understand that the storage account does not belong to this resource group but how do I write the ARM template to look for the storage account from another group?

Here is my template for the connection:

```
 {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
          "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
          "name": "[parameters('storageConName')]",
          "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
          "properties": {
            "displayName": "[parameters('storageConName')]",
            "parameterValues": {
              "accountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
              "accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value]"
            },
            "api": {
              "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('resourceGroupId'),'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/managedApis/azureblob')]"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: @Redseven- Could you please share the complete ARM template that you are trying to deploy so that we can test and assist you further

Comment: make Sure both are in same region.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what was wrong, the properties:api:id was using the *logic App resource group id* where it should be using the *storage accounts resource group id*.

I misunderstood that this was the resource group where I wanted the connection to be created.